# how to approach inserting value to tables with columns that depend on other tables

Tags: sql

For example I have three tables named **Addresses**, **People** and **Households**.

- `Addresses` table should have no problems, since everything from
  there will be coming from the user input in a form.
- `People` has a foreign key for `addressId`. To achieve this, I make
  the `Address` be filled up first by the user, and use
  `LAST_INSERT_ID()` so the value will be ready to use for the next
  insert into `People`.
- `People` also has a foreign key for `householdId` so I can easily see which household a person blongs, but the `Households` table is yet to be filled.
- However, `Households` also needs foreign keys from `People`. `lastName`,`firstName`,`addressId` will be taken from the person that is the head of the household, which has its own boolean column.

With a scenario like this I can only imagine to insert `People` first without the `householdId`, then insert `Households` to get data from the form and create the `householdId`. Now that I have both partial entries, I can now update `Households` with the `lastName`,`firstName`,`addressId` and then get to update `People` with the `householdId`. I think it works but very tedious. Is there something to solve this problem?

Comment: It's not clear what is a data source for inserts. Are you loading data from an external source or creating a user UI to enter this info?

Comment: You could use deferred constraints, then the order of inserts doesn't matter.

Comment: But doubt the foreign key between Households and People. You need a many-to-many relationship table between those two

Comment: Why though? Without a foreign key "householdId" in People, how can I view the members of that certain household?

Answer (score 0):

it was poorly designed !
the relationship between People and Households is one to many. People can have one or many Households and Household can have only one People.
For that, no need to have foreign key in People table, only the id of People must be added in Households Table.
afterwards, the form insertion will be easier

Comment: thats not the case - a household can be one person in an address or a family so it can have many people BUT people belong in one household only. And I already have personId FK in households.

Comment: so no need to have householdID in People table ?

Comment: I still need the householdId in People. How should I get which persons belong in a household without a connection to Households?